# If L is a regular language, how to show that cut(L) is not necessarily regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Given that L is a regular language. How do I show that cut(L) = {ac | abc ∈ L and |a| = |b| = |c|} is not necessarily regular?

My thought process is that this problem can be re-written as:

cut(L) = {aⁿcⁿ | aⁿbⁿcⁿ ∈ L where n ≥ 0}

I can then convert this to aᵖbᵖcᵖ, and have y consist entirely of 'a's as |xy| ≤ p
I can then pump y up or down, which will cause aᵖ⁺ᵐbᵖcᵖ, where m ≠ 0, making it no longer part of the language, thus being not regular.

However, I am confused as to whether I should be pumping aⁿcⁿ or aⁿbⁿcⁿ or if it even matters which one I do (both should give same result, but I'm not sure which one is the 'correct' one to actually pump)

I am also a bit unsure if my conversion of cut(L) = {ac | abc ∈ L and |a| = |b| = |c|} to cut(L) = {aⁿcⁿ | aⁿbⁿcⁿ ∈ L where n ≥ 0} is allowed either.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392640/given-fa-ac-mid-abc-in-a-and-a-b-c-why-is-fl-not).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thanks, I had a look through your response, however it looks to be  Myhill–Nerode theorem (correct me if I'm mistaken) which I have not learnt about. I was wondering if there was a way to prove this question with the pumping lemma, and whether my 'proof' above had any validity, or if for a question like this Myhill–Nerode theorem is the way to go, as pumping lemma would be too messy or hard.